# Delete spaces between words textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, spaces

I have an UITextField were you need to enter a city name. That city name is linked to an url: For example mywebsite/oslo

But, when I enter New York than is it not an correct url. mywebsite/new york
It needs to be this http://www.website.com/New-York 
How can I make a UITextField that replaces spaces with: --> -

Thanks for your help!

```
- (void)configureControls {


[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{

    if (self.weatherModel.lastLoadFailed) {
        self.locationTextField.enabled = YES;
        self.saveButton.hidden = NO;
        self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.settingsModel.location = self.locationTextField.text;


    PWForecastModel *forecast = self.weatherModel.sevenDayForecast[0];
    NSString *backgroundName = [PWHelper backgroundFileNameForConditionCode:forecast.conditions.conditionCode asDaytime:[[NSDate date] isDayTime]];
    if (![[NSDate date] isDayTime]) {
        [self styleControlsForDarkBackground];
    }
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:backgroundName];
    self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.weatherModel.cityName];
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This only, removes characters from the beginning and end of your string,

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the delegate method `textFieldShouldEndEditing` . There You just use this `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` . Or also use this on any event . That's all . Hope this helps .

Reference:

```
   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       //    NSString *str=  [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
        //    NSLog(@"Testing: %@",str);
 textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.myweb.com/%@",[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"]];
            return YES;
        }
```

I think , You just need this :

```
[self.weatherModel.cityName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
```

Comment: Does this work? self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.weatherModel.cityName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"]];

Comment: If this **self.weatherModel.cityName** could be getting the correct value . Then It should work..

Comment: More code than necessary, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"` is not needed and drop the last `]` as well of course.

Comment: self.weatherModel.cityName is the NSString

Comment: Then what's your problem ..?

Comment: Is doesn't work... Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x8987560 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: That clearly says , This should be the JSON parsing exception . Not by this . Can you post your code..

Comment: I've added it in the question

Comment: Check with this : **NSLog(@" %@", self.weatherModel.cityName);**

Comment: No comment in the log... What to do?

Comment: Then check with where you are upto **set self.weatherModel.cityName**

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"Hi I am Indra          ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

For Replace space from string

```
NSString *str = @"This is a string";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                     withString:@""];
```

Comment: This only, removes characters from the beginning and end of your string,

Comment: So you want to remove space between string??

Comment: I don't . But the Op requirement is like that . Read that

Comment: Yes between strings. Like New-York or San-Fransisco. Because otherwise it is not a correct URL.